# Liquid - Load all products from collection handler not working

Tags: shopify, liquid, handle

I am trying to **load all products by the given handler from a collection**.

They will click on a box (each box is a different collection), then it should load all products for that collection.

My issue is that my assigned variable cannot read the input from javascript.
I am doing onclick(id, name, handle) where i catch the handle and pass it to the liquid.

***My code is:***

```
function loadProducts(collectionH) {

var html = '';
var handlerString = collectionH;
console.log('Loading products...');    

{{collectionHandleNew}} = handlerString;
    
console.log({{collectionHandleNew}}); // log the handler


 // Make sure the current product name is loaded
{% if collectionHandleNew -%}
{% if selectedCategory -%}
 

console.log('Collection handle is set: ' + {{collectionHandleNew}});



      {%- for product in collections[collectionHandleNew].products -%}
          console.log({{product.id}});
      {%- endfor -%}



  {% else -%}
      console.log('Selected category not found');
  {% endif -%}
{% else -%}
    console.log('Collection handle is not available');
{% endif -%}

return html;

}
```

***The console is showing this:***
[view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D47ln.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to remember that Liquid and Javascript serve two completely different purposes:

- Liquid is a **templating** language that is parsed server-side to generate the documents that are sent to the client's browser, and is never seen by the client.
- Javascript is a **programming** language that is parsed client-side to do dynamic things on the page and is never executed on the server.

Why is this distinction important? Because it means that we can use Liquid to generate Javascript, but the reverse is never true.  It also means that any variables that we pass from Liquid to Javascript will only be current as of the time the document is generated and cannot be affected by anything that happens on the page once it's been rendered!

If your code needs to fetch a collection dynamically, I would recommend creating a function that takes a collection handle and loads the products entirely through Javascript using your favourite tool (`fetch`, `jQuery.getJSON`, `XMLHttpRequest`, `Axios`, etc).

To fetch products from a collection from the storefront, you can use `/collections/<some-collection-handle>/products.json` (for example, `/collections/drawstring-bag-hoodies/products.json`). If you're feeling fancy, you might also consider looking into the [storefront GraphQL API](https://shopify.dev/api/storefront) instead of the traditional REST API.

One final note: Whenever you are dumping variables from Liquid into Javascript, I *strongly* recommend using the [`| json` Liquid filter](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters/additional-filters#json) to ensure that the resulting output is Javascript-legal.  There are lots of ways a Liquid variable dump can break Javascript, such as when the variable is unexpectedly empty, when it contains `'` or `"`, when it contains line breaks, etc.  By running the Liquid variable through this filter, the resulting output will be wrapped in the appropriate brackets or quotes, all special characters within will be properly escaped, and empty values will print `null`.